# Add internal test only application when doing mix test

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I am trying to figure out how to test my project and I was going to try to make Fakes for the edges of my system. In my case that is the network, a udp socket. To do that, I was going to start up a GenServer to manage the "faked" open connections. I can't seem to make a test only application and add it without mix getting mad. Given this application I defined in `test/support`

```
defmodule MyProjectTest.Application do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      GenUdpFake,
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyProjectTest.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

I tried to use the following in my mix.exs

```
  def application do
    [
      mod: {MyProject.Application, []},
      extra_applications: [:logger, :runtime_tools] ++ extra_applications(Mix.env())
    ]
  end

  defp extra_applications(:test) do
    [MyProjectTest.Application]
  end

  defp extra_applications(_) do
    []
  end
```

I always get the following error running `mix test`.

```
** (Mix) Could not start application Elixir.MyProjectTest.Application: could not find application file: Elixir.MyProjectTest.Application.app
```

However, I even went into the build folder and found `_build/test/lib/my_project/ebin/Elixir.MyProjectTest.Application.beam`. I even found it in `my_project.app` under the modules, but not the applications. So, I am supper confused what I am doing wrong. I can't seem to find any info about adding an application that isn't from dependencies to the `extra_application:` property. The mix documentation doesn't really tell me much more. The application documentation doesn't really say anything. I am pretty sure all I want is `'Elixir.MyProjectTest.Application'` to be included in the applications section of `my_project.app`. Is this something I am not allowed to do? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Do you configure the `elixirc_paths` in the `def project...`  of your mix.exs? It defaults to `"lib"`, it could be you have to add the `"test/support"` folder for `Mix.env() == :test`.

Comment: @jakobfp The phoenix template ended up putting that in. I have 
```defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "test/support"]```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that although the module is called Application, it's not a beam application.

You probably want to list it in the `children` of your test supervision tree, rather than the `extra_applications`. Or skip the extra application module completely, and put `GenUdpFake` in the `children`.

Another option is to start the fake in your test setup, with

```elixir
{:ok, _} = start_supervised(GenUdpFake)
```

Comment: Maybe? I can try. I feel like part of my problem is I am trying to do something a lot of developers don't do. I want integration test level of confidence with unit test levels of speed. So I want to test "end-to-end" but I want to control the ends. In OOP, I would just use dependency injection, but I am trying to not just remake a java project in elixir.

Comment: Dependency injection is a valid approach in Elixir too. You can swap out the module implementation for the fake one when running the tests. You may find reading a book such as [Testing Elixir](https://pragprog.com/titles/lmelixir/testing-elixir/) useful. Chapter 2 is about integration tests.